# How do i add git fetch tags in a declarative jenkins pipeline script

Tags: git, jenkins

I am fairly new with Jenkins and Git and I am still trying to figure out how to use the jenkins declarative pipeline script. I also have very minimal programming background so the groovy script is a bit new to me.

In my declarative pipeline script, I want to be able to fetch all of my git tags and descriptions while pulling the repository in the jenkins build process.

Currently what i have is this:

```
stage ('get_repo') {
    checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
        branches: [[name: '*/rc']], 
        doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, 
        extensions: [], 
        submoduleCfg: [], 
        userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'git',
                             url: 'git@bitbucket.org:myrepo/myrepo.git']]])
}
```

I am not sure what I should add. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
      branches: [[name: '*/master']],
      doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false,
      extensions: [[$class: 'CloneOption',
               depth: 0,
               **noTags**: **false**,
               reference: '', shallow: false]],
      submoduleCfg: [],
      userRemoteConfigs: [[]]]
)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Consider reading this article on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). In addition to the code you've provided, try to give some explanation on why and how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To fetch a particular tag from git in a declarative pipeline use the following  code

`checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url:<git repo URL> ]], branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/v1.2.0' ]]], poll: false`

the above code can be used to fetch tag v1.2.0 from your git hub URL specified.

this can also be added as a stage as given below

```
 stage('Cloning from Git') { 
          steps { 
              checkout scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', userRemoteConfigs: [[url: gitcode ]], branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/' + "${tag}"]]], poll: false
          
          }
      }
```

here `gitcode` and `tag` are variables containing Git URL and Tag name respectively.